# how to pass handler using intent

Tags: android, android-intent

there are 2 activity  A and Screen 
in A Activity , i made handler and want to pass it to screen activity

```
Handler error_handler = new Handler() {
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
}};

Intent loginButton_intent = new Intent(A.this, Screen.class);
loginButton_intent.putExtra("URL", URL);
loginButton_intent.putExtra("IP_Addres", dvr_login_data.IP_Addres);
loginButton_intent.("HAND", error_handler); <- but this code is error
```

how can i pass handler ?
plz warm-answer

Comment: Can you please be more specific what are you trying to do. I have the feeling that you are trying to do something common in uncommon way. If you want to access functions of class A from the class Screen then there are other ways to do that then to put Handler in the intent.

Comment: see this answer:

[android passing a service a handler][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252246/android-passing-a-service-a-handler


a bit late but hope it helps

Comment: see this answer:

[android passing a service a ha][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252246/android-passing-a-service-a-handler

Comment: see this answer:

[android passing a service a ha][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252246/android-passing-a-service-a-handler

a bit late but hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to keep it short, you can't...`Handler` implements neithor `Serializable` nor `Parcelable` so it cannot be put as an `extra`...The Object Transported using Intents must follow eithor of those protocols.

*Speculation*
I suppose, there's an alternative that would involve creating a `Service` to act as a middle man. But that'll require some testing.

Answer (score 5):

still looking for an answer?
I had the same problem and found this question through google, so others might show up as well.

Anyways, I found my solution to the problem of using a handler between a service and an activity in the Android documentation. Just look at the Remote Messenger Service Sample right here: [Remote Messenger Service Sample](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample)

Basically they are using a messenger as client interface for a local handler in the service.

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass Handler directly through an Activity's Extras, but you can pass in Messenger(handler).

Comment: can you clarify?