# Android trying to get my app to talk to a local service

Tags: android, service

I have created a Service locally and was wondering if there was a way to call its methods.  I was thinking about using stream sockets and have the client send messages to the service, but this seems like to much work.
The code I have to create the service

```
public class Welcome extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID=1337;
    private Timer timer=new Timer();
    private int count=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         // set up buttons
        View mAppoitment = findViewById(R.id.appoitment);
        mAppoitment.setOnClickListener(this);

    // start background thread
        Log.v("TED:", "Starting thread");
        startService(new Intent(Welcome.this,
                BackgroundService.class));
```

Ted

Comment: send an `Intent` to the service. the service should register a broadcast receiver to receive specific intents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider exposing an AIDL interface from the service. For more details and an example refer to documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html

Another option is to have service register a broadcast receiver and sent Intents to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at previous answers: [Android: Passing a Service a Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252246/android-passing-a-service-a-handler).

The messenger interface gets around the AIDL complexity (somewhat): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample

Generally I've used the ServiceConnection and passed a Handler instance: you can see how to use the ServiceConnection at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample