# Android Service updates table; How to get corresponding ListView to update?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-service

Let's say I have a long-running service that monitors a network of external devices. Whenever it discovers a new device in the network, it adds a row to a table in a local SQLite database, and whenever it detects a change of state on a known device, it updates the corresponding row in the table. (BTW, there's no way to predict how frequently or infrequently these discoveries and updates will occur -- the external network marches to its own drummer!)

Now, let's also say I have an Activity (in the same process) that includes a ListView backed by the above-mentioned table. At the precise moment that the ListView is initially populated, it's of course in sync with the backing table -- but a moment (or two, or three) afterwards, because of changes in the external device network, the table changes, courtesy of the Service.

What's the best way for the Service to inform the Activity that it needs to refresh the ListView, i.e., call requery() on the Cursor, and then call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter?

I've seen a couple of posts here on SO in which the approach seemed to be "register a broadcastReceiver on the Activity, and send a broadcast Intent from the Service" -- but that seems a bit overkill for a local Service. Isn't there some simpler way?

For instance, I'm thinking that since I can get a handle to the local Service object via a Binder object, I might be able to register some kind of callback to the Activity, to be called by the service when needed. Does this sound like it would work? (Or would I be entering blind alley?)

Looking forward to your insights.

M

Comment: Your approach will work, but there is something you need to remember. UI could only be updated from one single thread and thats the one activity started working on. I normally use a handler and send a message to it.

Comment: Yeah, I woke up this morning thinking that could be a potential problem. Thanks for the heads-up/confirmation. :)

Comment: So, for the moment, I have my Service sending messages to a Handler I create in the Activity thread. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1252505/1337498); and bearing in mind that I get to have fun re-coding it all if I decide I want the Service running in a different process. But for now it's fine, and the fact that I have to bind the Service to tell it about the Handler doesn't add a lot of code I wouldn't have had to write anyway, since the Activity will also use the Service to send commands to the devices in the external network.